# Genericity by names

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

If $P$ is a notion of forcing in $M$, then $G$ is a $P$-generic filter over $M$ if $G\subseteq P$ is a filter, and for every $D\in M$ which is a dense subset of $P$, $G\cap D\neq\varnothing$.

Equivalently we can replace $D$ being dense by being pre-dense, open dense, or a maximal antichain.

Given such a generic filter, and $\dot x$ which is a $P$-name, we can define the interpretation of $\dot x$ by the filter $G$ by recursion, $$\dot x^G=\{\dot y^G\mid\exists p\in G:\langle p,\dot y\rangle\in\dot x\}.$$

Clearly, we don't *need* genericity in order to interpret names. We can talk about interpretation using arbitrary filters.

> **Question.** Given a filter $G$, is there some reasonable condition stating that $G$ is generic if and only if it interprets certain names (e.g. names which are forced to be ordinals) "properly"?

Comment: I suppose saying that $G$ is generic iff it interprets the canonical name $\dot{G}$ to be a filter generic over the ground model isn't helpful.

Comment: Miha, yeah, it's not quite what I was aiming for. I was looking more for something like "every name of an ordinal is interpreted as an ordinal".

Comment: In that direction you get some pretty underwhelming results. For example, if $x$ is some arbitrary nonempty set, $G$ is generic iff it interprets every name for $x$ as $x$: for any maximal antichain $A$ build a name $\tau_A$ by mixing check names $\check{x}$ over $A$. This will be interpreted to be $x$ iff $G$ meets $A$ and will be empty otherwise.

Comment: @Miha: But there is an inherent circularity in your idea. We don't know if something is a name for $x$ without an interpretation, unless $1\Vdash\dot x=\check x$, in which case your argument of using antichain fails.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. What you call circularity I would just call taking the usual definition of genericity and finding an equivalent. Specifically, for my $\tau_A$ we DO have $1\Vdash \tau_A= \check{x}$, if we interpret $1\Vdash\varphi$ to say that after interpreting by any (real) generic $\varphi$ holds (you can, and probably should, use the internal definition of the forcing relation, though). On the other hand, if a filter $H$ misses the antichain $A$, it will interpret $\tau_A$ to be empty, which we can detect.

Comment: Miha, forgive me for trespassing on your idea---I had the same thought in my answer.  Asaf, I think your ordered pairs for the names are reversing the usual convention, since we think of the pairs as like a function, mapping a name to the value that it is an element. (That is, shouldn't you have $\langle \dot y,p\rangle$?)

Comment: Oh, I see that Miha's idea was different than I had thought at first, and not the same as what I wrote. But it is a good idea!

Comment: Joel, the convention I know is that $p$ forces $\dot y$ to be an element, so $p$ is in the domain, and $\dot y$ is in the range. So $\langle p,\dot y\rangle$. I always found it more natural too, for some reason.

Comment: I see (and probably you force upwards as well!). The idea of the usual convention is that names are like characteristic functions, but with truth values in the forcing notion.

Comment: @Joel: I have **never** forced upwards. :-)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Not at all. And I see you've developed my suggestion nicely in your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is fairly open-ended, but here is one way to do it. For any antichain $A\subset P$, consider the name $\dot a_A=\{\langle\check a,a\rangle\mid a\in A\}$, which is a mixture of the elements of $A$ on the antichain $A$. This is the name that is trying to be an element of $A$, with values determined by $A$ itself.

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent, for a filter $G\subset P$.

1. $G$ is $V$-generic.
2. $(\dot a_A)^G\in A$ for each maximal antichain $A\subset P$.
3. $(\dot a_A)^G$ is nonempty for every maximal antichain.

Proof. The filter $G$ is generic if and only if it meets every maximal antichain, and in this case, 2 will hold, and clearly 2 implies 3. If 3 holds, then there must be some $a\in A\cap G$, and so $G$ will be $V$-generic. QED

Miha suggests a similar idea in the comments, namely, take any nonempty set $x$, and consider the names $\dot x=\{\langle\check y,a\rangle \mid y\in x\text{ and }a\in A\}$, for any maximal antichain $A$. Miha's observation is that although every condition forces $\check x=\dot x$, nevertheless if $G$ is not generic and misses the antichain $A$, then $\dot x^G$ will be empty. This idea arrives at the following, which seems to meet the requirement of your question.

**Theorem.** (Miha Habič, in comments) The following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is $V$-generic.
2. $G$ interprets all names for non-zero ordinals as non-zero ordinals. That is, if $\mathbb{1}\Vdash(\tau$ is a nonzero ordinal), then $\tau^G$ is a nonzero-ordinal.
3. $G$ interprets all names for the number $1$ correctly.

Proof. Clearly 1 implies 2 and 3. Conversely, if 2 or 3 holds, let $A$ be any maximal antichain and let $\tau=\{\langle 0,a\rangle \mid a\in A\}$. This is a name forced to be the ordinal $1$, and it is easy to see that $\tau^G$ is either $0$ or $1$, depending on whether $G$ meets $A$. So $1$ holds. QED

One can use dense sets instead of antichains, which will avoid a dependence on AC.

Lastly, let me add then when you are entertaining the idea of interpreting names via a filter that is not generic, then you should not be using the value as you have defined it, but rather you should be using the [Boolean ultrapower](http://jdh.hamkins.org/boolean-ultrapowers/) instead. In this method, you use the Boolean algebra rather than just a partial order, and define the equivalence on names $\sigma=_G\tau\iff[\![\sigma=\tau]\!]\in G$, and similarly for $\sigma\in_G\tau$. Now, the ultrapower map is $x\mapsto [\check x]_G$, meaning the equivalence class under this equivalence relation. The result is an elementary embedding $$j:V\to\check V_G\subseteq  V^{\mathbb{B}}/G,$$whose target is the ground model of the corresponding quotient $V^{\mathbb{B}}/G$. The following theorem appears in the Boolean ultrapower paper:

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent:

1. $G\subset P$ is $V$-generic.
2. The Boolean ultrapower by $G$ is an isomorphism of $V$ with $\check V/G$.

This theorem is part of the explanation that "non-generic" is the right generalization of "non-principal" when considering the ultrapower on a complete Boolean algebra instead of merely on a powerset.

Comment: Thank you Joel. It's been helpful, and it also means that I'll have to do all the definitions and proofs the hard way... :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Oh, of course you don't. It's a work in progress... I'll keep you posted. :)